# Bit Rate Throttling on Windows 10 using IIS 10 for Dash Playback

Tags: bandwidth, throttling

I am running IIS 10, (on windows 10). How to do bit rate throttle for DASH playback testing?

After searching found the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-performance-settings/use-bit-rate-throttling) but after installing IIS web platform, the IIS Media services 4.1 link is broken. 
Is there any way to host Media files and do bit throttling on windows?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about web server administration, not computer programming. Try https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the bandwidth throttling using the netBalancer software. https://netbalancer.com/download
Its very easy , just check the process you want to limit and set the upload/download limit.